# Group order $3$ associative property - $27$ cases.

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

*Am a novice, & am practicing to have hold of the subject. Also, request source with such questions as examples.*

Need show all the $27$ cases for a group's associativity property, with three elements.

As know *by group table of $3$ elements* that there can be only 3 elements $e, b,c$, as below:

> $$
> \begin{array}{c|lcr}
>  & e & a & b \\
> \hline
> e & e & a & b \\
> a & a & b & e \\
> b & b & e & a
> \end{array}$$

For a group $G$ described by its elements, here $3$, & the operation (let, *), the associative property implies: $\alpha*(\beta*\gamma) = (\alpha*\beta)*\gamma$. 
As can have for each of the $3$ elements : $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, the values : $e, a, b$; so the possibilities are : $3*3*3 =27$.

For the group however, can have only $6$ cases as shown below:

(i) $a*(b*e) = (a*b)*e$, 
(ii) $a*(e*b) = (a*e)*b$, 
(iii) $b*(a*e) = (b*a)*e$, 
(iv) $b*(e*a) = (b*e)*a$, 
(v) $e*(a*b) = (e*a)*b$, 
(vi) $e*(b*a) = (e*b)*a$,

There is no way, can proceed to get 21 more cases in associativity.

But, it is given in the book 'Abstract Algebra: A First Undergraduate Course' , by 'Hillman', on pg. #57 that there are $27$ cases to check for associativity of a group of $3$ elements, as shown below: 
[image]

I can only think of $27$ cases for checking associativity when any of the $3$ elements : $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ can be $a,b,e$ simultaneously, i.e it is possible to have a case like : $a*(a*a)$, & so on.

Below are the $27$ possible cases with that possibility, but I feel that these are invalid for the case of group, as all $3$ elements should be different:

(vii) $a*(a*a) = (a*a)*a$, 
(viii) $b*(b*b) = (b*b)*b$, 
(ix) $e*(e*e) = (e*e)*e$, 
(x) $a*(b*a) = (a*b)*a$, --- (xi) $a*(a*b) = (a*a)*b$
(xii) $a*(e*a) = (a*e)*a$, --- (xiii) $a*(a*e) = (a*a)*e$
(xiv) $e*(b*a) = (e*b)*a$, --- (xv) $e*(a*b) = (e*a)*b$
(xvi) $e*(e*a) = (e*e)*a$, --- (xvii) $e*(a*e) = (e*a)*e$
(xviii) $b*(b*a) = (b*b)*a$, --- (xix) $b*(a*b) = (b*a)*b$, 
(xx) $b*(e*a) = (b*e)*a$, --- (xxi) $b*(a*e) = (b*a)*e$,
(xxii) $a*(b*b) = (a*b)*b$, 
(xxiii) $a*(e*e) = (a*e)*e$, 
(xxiv) $b*(a*a) = (b*a)*a$, 
(xxv) $b*(e*e) = (b*e)*e$, 
(xxvi) $e*(a*a) = (e*a)*a$, 
(xxvii) $e*(b*b) = (e*b)*b$,

Comment: The second approach is the right one. There's nothing preventing you from checking that $a* (b*b) = (a*b) * b$, for instance. In the integers, that'd be like checking that $1 + (2 + 2) = (1+2) + 2$, i.e., $1 + 4 = 3 + 2$. That's a totally reasonable thing to check. I don't understand why you say "I feel that there are invalid for the case of  group, as all 3 elements should be different." It's true that the three elements of the group must be different from one another, but it's perfectly common to apply an operation to two elements that happen to be the same.

Comment: @JohnHughes So, it means that the group table shows here only 3 elements with identity(as a must); but in actual cases identity may not be involved. I hope that for general case representation by 'group-table' (of $n$ elements), there are $n-1$ elements (repeatable) + identity shown in the group table. I mean by above that : Apart from identity, there is no such special fixed element in 'group table' representation.

Comment: If you already verified that $e$ is an identity, then indeed you need not really check any of the cases that invilve $e$ somewhere. This is because already the identity  property guarantees without further look into the multiplicatin table that e.g. $a*(b*e)=a*b=(a*b)*e$, no matter what $*$ does to other elements (and no matter if $a$ and/or $b$ are equal to $e$ (or to one another). So with this in mind (i.e., after verifying that $e$ acts as identity and remarking that all cases involving $e$ are automatically associative, you still need to check the oher $8$ cases (with duplicates of course)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have listed 10 cases that only need be checked, if identity element occurance cases are to be ignored: Case #: (v), (vi), (vii), (viii), (x), (xi), (xviii), (xix), (xxii), (xxiv). Please confirm its correctness.

Comment: If the identity doesn't occur, all three of the arguments are in $\{a, b\}$, so there are only $2^3 = 8$ possibilities.

Comment: @Travis Had wrongly written $e$ as $c$ in cases (v), (vi) leading to two extra cases; edited. I hope you meant : $2$ options for first place* $2$ options for second place * $2$ options for third place = $2^3=8$.

Comment: There is no reason why, for instance, $(a*a)*b=a*(a*b)$ should hold for a generic binary operation. So indeed you have to check $n^3$ cases, where $n$ is the number of elements in the set: there's no way to exclude *a priori* the cases where two of the elements coincide. By the way, it's not difficult to find operations such that $(x*x)*x=x*(x*x)$ doesn't hold for every $x$. Of course, once you know that the operation has an identity, the triples involving it can be safely removed, leading to just $(n-1)^3$ checks.

Comment: @jiten Yes, that's correct.